# Can I use an NFC reader as if it was a dynamic tag?

Tags: android, nfc

For example if I have the reader connected to a PC, on the PC screen I select "open url 1", tap my NFC phone to the reader and it will open url 1. I select on the screen "open url 2", tap my phone to the reader and it opens url 2?

I thought peer to peer mode would enable something like this but I cannot find much information.

Answer (score 0):

I havn't tried or something, but I think [this site](http://www.grundid.de/nfc/) is gonna help you. 
The only thing I know is that's possible, and not really hard.